# Firefox not handling Applescript to select from drop down list same as Google Chrome

Tags: html, forms, applescript

I am using an Applescript to tab to and select an item from a dropdown box on a form, and return to the starting field. Using Firefox 57.0, both "Cakes, large" (the first item with the first letter "C") and "Cocktails" get selected.  Using Google Chrome 63.0 only "Cocktails" gets selected, which is what I want.  Any ideas how to get the desired result in Firefox?

Applescript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "System Events" to key code 48
    tell application "System Events" to key code 49
    keystroke "Cocktails"
    tell application "System Events" to key code 48 using shift down
    tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using command down
end tell
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <select class="category-multi" id="RecipeTypes" multiple="multiple" name="RecipeTypes" style="display: none"><option selected="selected" value="85">Fried doughs</option>
<option selected="selected" value="64">Mousses, trifles, custards &amp; creams</option>
</select>    
    <select class="form-control category-ddl" id="RecipeTypesDDL" name="RecipeTypesDDL"><option value=""></option>
<option value="41">Baked &amp; steamed desserts</option>
<option value="42">Beverages / drinks (no-alcohol)</option>
<option value="82">Bread &amp; buns, sweet</option>
<option value="43">Bread &amp; rolls, savory</option>
<option value="44">Brownies, slices &amp; bars</option>
<option value="45">Cakes, large</option>
<option value="46">Cakes, small</option>
<option value="47">Candy / sweets</option>
<option value="49">Cheesecakes</option>
<option value="50">Children &amp; baby food</option>
<option value="51">Chili</option>
<option value="52">Chutneys, pickles &amp; relishes</option>
<option value="53">Cocktails / drinks (with alcohol)</option>
<option value="54">Cookies, biscuits &amp; crackers</option>
<option value="55">Crumbles, cobblers, crisps &amp; bettys</option>
<option value="56">Curry</option>
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but a few comments about your AppleScript: you don't need nested `tell application "System Events"`.  Keep the first and last line as a `tell...end tell` block, then delete every other `tell application "System Events" to` from inside it.  Also, to make it more readable, you can use `keystroke tab` instead of `key code 48`; and `keystroke space` instead of `key code 49`.

Comment: Also, dropdown lists don't allow multiple selections and the `<select>` tag that defines options for "Cakes", "Cocktails", etc. doesn't have its `multiple` attribute set. As it stands, I tested this both in *Chrome* and *Firefox* (same versions) and both browsers could only choose one option.  So I added the attribute `multiple="multiple"` to the second `<select>` tag, and the element became a scroll-list that permits multiple selections.  Again, both *Chrome* and *Firefox* performed as expected on my system, which leads me to believe that inserting `delay 0.5` between each line might help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a solution either, but I did want to pass this tip along.  FireFox is NOT scriptable, but Chrome is.  You can use AppleScript to inject JavaScript into a Chrome page, and do just about anything.  This is much, much more reliable than using UI scripting, which is all you can do with FireFox.  So I'd dump Firefox for this task, and just use Chrome.

Comment: Really want to stay with Firefox.  Is there a way with applescript to keep the first item (Cakes, large) in the dropdown list from being selected?  Alternatively, deleting the first item after the fact with applescript? I tried starting Firefox in safe mode and that did not solve the problem.

Comment: By the way this page does use AJAX.